# MySQL Wildcard Issue

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I'm trying to write a query that returns all the rows that have a specific date in the timestamp column,

The date format in the timestamp column is

`2014-01-07 10:20:10`

The Query I wrote does not return any results  `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

`SELECT * FROM observium.syslog WHERE 'timestamp' LIKE '2014-01-07%';`

Any idea how I can do this right?

Comment: what is the datatype of the column? datetime or date or timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT * FROM observium.syslog WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = '2014-01-07'
```

Or try the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT * FROM observium.syslog WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y %m %d') = DATE_FORMAT('2014-01-07', '%Y %m %d')
```

Comment: `Empty set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)` @Aziz 
`mysql> SHOW WARNINGS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: 'timestamp'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: the `DATE_FORMAT()` in the query did return the correct results. Thanks!